# Reloading navigation bar

Tags: ios, navigation, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

How can I reload/reassign navigation bar items? I use some libraries that change navigation bar and sometimes I have a bag in which all navigation items disappear. I have reassigned right items in `viewWillAppear` like:

```
UIButton *actionButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
actionButton.frame = CGRectMake(270, 0, 50, 50);
actionButton.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = YES;
[actionButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"share.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[actionButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"share-active.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
[actionButton addTarget:self action:@selector(presentActivity) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
UIBarButtonItem *actionBarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithCustomView:actionButton];
actionBarButton.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = actionBarButton;
```

But it does not work and sometimes I do not have any navigation items.

Comment: What library are you using? You need to find out at what point the library is messing with your toolbars and call your code after that or prevent it from happening

Comment: AMScrollingNavbar, developer of it do not know that happens=/

Comment: Okay, some information from your question is missing. What do you mean by *bag*? How are you connecting your View Controllers with the Navigation Controller (assuming one Storyboard is being used)?

Comment: I don't think that library is at fault as it is not setting barButtonItems anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UIBarButtonItem
```

is not child of UIButton.

here is not known methods like `setImage:forState:` etc.

create  and custon an UITabBarButton like this

```
UIBarButtonItem *newBackButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(goBack)];
    newBackButton.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"back"];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem=newBackButton;
```

also verify if method with this code will be called when `viewDidLoad`

Answer (score 0):

Check out this like https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uinavigationbar_class/Reference/UINavigationBar.html the apple dev is awesome.

This is another good link
AppCoda has a lot of great tutorials this one has everything you need to know about Nav Bars
http://www.appcoda.com/customize-navigation-status-bar-ios-7/

and you could also use perform segue with identifier method and to send a string or something to a new view controller and then when you see that string is equal to what you want use an if statement in your viewWillAppear method.